# How to make work search bar passing props through components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to filter data and implement in search bar. In **Hook/index.js** component I am fetching and filtering data inside **useEffects**. Then I am passing props in **App.js**. Afterwards I have a **Searchbar** component, where I am listening to the input and here it must work. I get **undefined**.

**Hook/index.js** component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./hook.scss";

export default () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result))
      .catch((err) => console.log("error"));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchResult =
      data && data.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search));
    setSearch(searchResult);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return [data, error];
};
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState }from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";
import Flag from "./components/Flag";
import useCountries from "./Hooks";
import CountryList from "./components/CountryList";



import "./App.scss";

export default function App()  {
  const [data, error] = useCountries();

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchBar />  //   {/*this throws an error <SearchBar data={data}/> */}
      <Header />
      {data &&
        data.map((country) => (
          <div className="CountryList" key={country.name}>
            <Flag flag={country.flag} />
            <CountryList
              population={country.population}
              name={country.name}
              region={country.region}
            />
            {country.languages.map((language, languageIndex) => (
              <CountryList key={languageIndex} language={language.name} />
            ))}
           
          </div>
        ))}
      <useCountries />
    </div>
  );
  return [data, error]
}
```

**Searchbar** component

```
import React, {useState} from "react";


import "./SearchBar.scss";

export default function SearchBar({data}) {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

   function handleChange(e) {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  } 
  return (
    <div className="SearchBar">
      <input
        className="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="search country ..."
        value={data}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      {data && data.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: {/*this throws an error <SearchBar data={data}/> */} What is the error that you get

Comment: Hey @sgrmhdk here it is
 Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, topLevelDomain, alpha2Code, alpha3Code, callingCodes, capital, altSpellings, region, subregion, population, latlng, demonym, area, gini, timezones, borders, nativeName, numericCode, currencies, languages, translations, flag, regionalBlocs, cioc}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: can you put console.log(data) in App.js.  Just to be sure whether data is populated and to see the structure of an object

Comment: Hey @sgrmhdk if I remove data={data} and console.log(data)  gives me the array of objects in console.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data variable to input instead of search variable.

In JS filter return array and DOM cannot display array since it is not html or jsx so you need to convert array to jsx with map. with map you can return array or jsx

```
   <div className="SearchBar">
        <input
           className="input"
           type="text"
           placeholder="search country ..."
           value={search} // change here 
           onChange={handleChange}
     />
     <ul>{(data || []).filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)).map(e=>(<li key={e.name}>{e.name}</li>))}</ul> /change here
    </div>
```

Comment: <ul>{data && data.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)).map(e=><li key={e.name}>{e.name}</li>)}</ul>

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqQ-kOchqHM&ab_channel=simonswiss

watch this youtube tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Your new `.filter()` Array contains Objects inside it! You need to `.map()` it before return as Objects are not valid as a React child.

```
{ data?.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)).map((element => 
<>
 /* Your code goes here! */
</>) }
```

Explanation:

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new Array and in your case your Array is filled with Objects, like this:

```
{data && data.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search))}
// The code above returns an Array just like below.

const array = [ {name: 'Brazil' /*...others properties*/}, {name: 'USA' /*...others properties*/}, {name: 'England' /*...others properties*/} ];
```

When you return `array`, React reject to mount your Objects, cus it can't understand what to do. That's why you map it, to have access to each Object inside it.

Comment: Hey @Iago Calazans thank you for responding again. 
But what do you mean? I didn't understand. Can you explain, please

Comment: Ok @Greg i'd made an explanation on the answer above! Cya! ☑️

Comment: @ Iago Calazans thank you very much,  that makes a sense. I'll try again.no success so far

Comment: @Greg where i've set /* Your code goes here */, try to overwrite with <div>{element.name}</div> and tell me if it works.

Comment: @ Iago Calazans now no errors,  it returns bunch of this [object Object] in search input  and the name from map function

Comment: Oh, then you need to do a map into the filter you’ve used on your first question listed file.

Comment: same as here you mean?

Comment: Yes, and when mapping remember that you can access all the objects properties!

Comment: @ Iago Calazans I'm kind of confused.  this has the same output. Check here , please
https://codesandbox.io/s/8458o?file=/src/Hooks/index.js

Comment: @Greg, if i was you i will use a Context to make it work as desired. Check how to at: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: The Context will run as your Hook/index.js and you can update it from SearchBar.

Comment: @ Iago Calazans ok, I'll take a look, how it works. thank you

Comment: That’s it! Looks like this question is answered, you should change the question title to “.filter() not working with React Child component” haha . The useContext will be another challenge to you and it’s logic is closely to your Hook anonymous function.